# In GSON, is there a way to deserialize a field in an inner class into the parent class?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

Using GSON, if I had some JSON that looked like this:

```
{
    "foo" : "asdf",
    "bar" : "jkl",
     "city": {
        "name": "Los Angeles",
        "country": "US"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to deserialize this into a class that looks like this just by using the SerializedName annotation?

```
public class SomeDto {
  String foo;
  String bar;
  String city;
  String country;
}
```

Instead of having to create inner classes and write a special Deserializer?

Maybe something like this?

```
@SerializedName("city.name")
private String city;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a single class, You can declare "city" as Map -

**Example.java**

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Example {
    String foo;
    String bar;
    Map<String, String> city;
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    public Map<String, String> getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(Map<String, String> city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Example [foo=" + foo + ", bar=" + bar + ", city=" + city + "]";
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import com.example.Example;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Main {
    private static Gson gson;

    static {
        gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "{\"foo\":\"asdf\",\"bar\":\"jkl\",\"city\":{\"name\":\"Los Angeles\",\"country\":\"US\"}}";
        Example info = gson.fromJson(s, Example.class);
        System.out.println(info);
   }
}
```

**Result**

```
Example [foo=asdf, bar=jkl, city={name=Los Angeles, country=US}]
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know - no. However, you can hide the serialization details behind a convenient interface.

For example:

```
public class SomeDto {
  private String foo;
  private String bar;
  private City city;

  public String getFoo() {...};
  public String getBar() {...};
  public String getCity() {return city.getName();};
  public String getCountry() {return city.getCountry();};
}
```